# relation of left and right cosets

Tags: group-theory

I am given a non-abelian group $G$ and $H\leq G$ a subgroup of $G$. $H$ is not required to be a normal subgroup of $G$. Is it true to claim that for every left coset $gH$, there is some $g'\in G$ s.t. $gH=Hg'$? If this is not true, can someone give me an example of such case? I tries to find in permutation groups $S_n$ but could not find something concrete. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the dihedral group with eight elements
$$
D_4=\{e, r, r^2, r^3, s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4\}
$$
where $r$ is $90^\circ$ rotation and the $s_i$ are reflections.  Take the subgroup $H=\{e, s_1\}$ where $s_1$ is reflection of the square about the vertical line down the center.  Then $rH=\{r, s_3\}$ where $s_3$ is reflection across the diagonal that goes from the upper right corner to the lower left.  But, $Hs_3=\{r^3, s_3\}$.

Comment: Ohhh yes I get it :). This is what I was searching for.